# Regex to find words having multiple occurrences of same string nearby position

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find words like follows using regex. But, I cannot find an idea to distinguish alphabets  from same alphabets.

For example :

```
text = ' I am sooo hungryyyy....Grrrh ...... helppp meeeeee '
pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL)
```

This pattern is not so helpful. Dont know why.
I want a regex to match all words like `sooo`, `hungryyyy`, `Grrrh` `....`. That means, if a letter is repeating simultaneously or next to each other at least 2 times.

Comment: What is the problem now? `re.findall(pattern, text)` gives `['o', 'y', '.', 'r', '.', 'p', 'e']`

Comment: @thefourtheye - But I want the entire word, one by one .

Comment: Do you have to use a regex or would another solution be acceptable?

Comment: **That means, if a letter is repeating**, How is `....` considered a letter here?

Comment: @thefourtheye - another solution is welcome.

Comment: @hwnd - I m not considering only letters. Moreover  i am working on emotional analysis. So these things generally matter to capture human emotions at writing some word patterns

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to match non-whitespace with consecutive characters, one could do:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'I am sooo hungryyyy....Grrrh ...... helppp meeeeee'
>>> matches = re.findall(r'(\S*?(.)\2+\S*?)', text)
>>> [x[0] for x in matches]
['sooo', 'hungryyyy', '....', 'Grrr', '......', 'helppp', 'meeeeee']
```

> That means, if a letter is repeating simultaneously or next to each other at least 2 times ...

However, if you're looking for word characters, your pattern would simply change:

```
>>> matches = re.findall(r'(\w*(\w)\2\w*)', text)
>>> [x[0] for x in matches]
['sooo', 'hungryyyy', 'Grrrh', 'helppp', 'meeeeee']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = ' I am sooo hungryyyy....Grrrh ...... helppp meeeeee '
for p in re.findall(r'(\w*(\w)\2\w*)', text):
    print p
```

*Gives:*

```
('sooo', 'o')
('hungryyyy', 'y')
('Grrrh', 'r')
('helppp', 'p')
('meeeeee', 'e')
```